# How to stop records from being overwritten on close

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

When I close the form, the current record overwrites the first record in the table.  If I include "Me.Undo" just before closing the form then the data on the form is changed but not in the underlying table.  How can I stop both of these from happening?

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT * FROM tblData ORDER BY tblData.txtName;"

Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSelect, dbOpenDynaset)
rst.MoveFirst
Me.txtName = rst!txtName
```

```vb
Private Sub btnClose_Click()

    'Me.Undo
    MsgBox " "
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmdata", acSaveNo
```

I would like to form to just close without displaying another record and without overwriting another record in the table.

Comment: Well, there seems a problem in the way you're writing the code. Do you have some other code running for `On_Current() events etc.? Maybe, you should provide more detail about the problem so that it can be replicated to find a solution.

Comment: First of all you need to decide whether this should be a **bound** form (then you don't need code to load or save records), or an **unbound** form (then nothing will be overwritten except by your code).

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that your Form has it's DataSource property set to 'tblData'.
So after you Form loads, the Form_Load() event fires, and you modify the first Record of the Table that is set in the Form's DataSource property.

This is the line that modify's the Form data: Me.txtName = rst!txtName